# Has_many rails association => NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have three classes in rails:

```
class Item::Part::Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_part, :foreign_key => 'item_part_id'
  self.table_name = 'item_part_elements'
end


class Item::Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :elements
  belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'item_id'
  self.table_name = 'item_parts'
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :parts
 self.table_name = 'item'
end
```

and if I call

```
@item.parts
```

it works fine, but if I make following call

```
@item_part.elements
```

throws an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method "elements"
```

Have I done my associations wrong or is there a different issue?

Comment: It is hard to say without not knowing all the details. How do you instantiate these instance variables? Also `NoMethodError`, but for what? For `nil`?

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method "elements" for Item::Part

Comment: Is `self` implied in your use of `item_part_id` and `item_id`?

Comment: self.table_name yes it is included

Comment: `belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => item_id` - should be `:item_id`

Comment: yeah, it is in my code as 'item_id', i forgot to put it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to specify class names for these associations. If you didn't have namespacing, these would work fine out of the box. But since you have `Item::Part::Element` instead of simply `Element`, you have to give ActiveRecord more to go on. Try this:

```
class Item::Part::Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_part, :foreign_key => 'item_part_id'
  self.table_name = 'item_part_elements'
end


class Item::Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :elements, :class_name => '::Item::Part::Element'
  belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'item_id'
  self.table_name = 'item_parts'
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :parts, :class_name => '::Item::Part'
 self.table_name = 'item'
end
```

The reason the class_names start with "::" is that it tells ActiveRecord you're namespacing from the top (root) of the namespace structure, instead of relative to the current model.

Honestly, I have a little trouble believing that `@item.parts` works properly!